# Recently-answered question does not show up in "Top Questions" list

Tags: bug

A question that I answered earlier today is mysteriously absent from the Top Questions list when I visit the site.  However, if I search for the question using keywords, and click the "Newest" tab, it appears right where it should be.  I am not familiar with this behavior -- is it normal?  I do see that the question currently has a vote score of -4 and one close vote, but I don't know if that accounts for what I am (not) seeing.

Comment: I think questions with total score less than -3 are not shown on the Top Questions list.

Comment: This is true, however, I have not found any official documentation stating this.  Perhaps the moderators know.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche Perhaps you can look on [meta.se] to find some statement and otherwise ask that question there. There is quite some behaviour of SE that is only 'documented' as a meta Q and A.

Answer (score 2):

Questions are dropped off the Home / Active tab once they reach a score of -4 on Main, or -8 on Meta. Since you mentioned that the question on Main that you were monitoring had a score of -4, this is most probably why it was no longer showing up on the Home page.

Source: [Meta sites' front pages should not hide questions with very low scores](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/62729#62769)